# VS2010 MVC and Entity Framework Model in Separate Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use an Entity Framework Model (in separate project) into an asp.net 4 MVC project (VS2010, C#)
If I create the EF inside the MVC project I have no problems.
I think I am missing some step.

things done:
1. added reference to the EF class project
2. added connection string in MVC web.config
3. added reference to System.Data.Entity in both web.config and project references

Now i can use the model only if I copy the .edmx file to the Models folder, but in this way the EF project is not external anymore.

What am I missing?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe related to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450682/how-to-locate-the-meta-files-generated-by-ef-in-a-class-library/6451139#6451139)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the entity model to create *public* classes? (Set in the models properties, and each of its entities.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
I've checked, and all the entities are already with public access (as it is by default, since i don't think I've touched this setting)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to done all necessary steps already. Try to remove the reference and add it again and **rebuild** it.

I had same problem but after **rebuild** the solution (1 MVC project and 1 data access layer project), everything works fine.