# How to locate the meta files generated by EF in a class library?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, class-library

I've moved my Entity Framework 4 model to a class library. The meta files are built to \bin\Debug

What is the connection string I use to locate the meta files in the class library? I have tried:

```
  <add name="Models.DataModelConnectionString" 
connectionString="metadata=res://MyClassLibrary, 1.0.0.0, neutral,
 null/bin/Debug/Models.DataModel.csdl|res://MyClassLibrary, 1.0.0.0, neutral,
 null/bin/Debug/Models.DataModel.ssdl|res://MyClassLibrary, 1.0.0.0, neutral,
 null/bin/Debug/Models.DataModel.msl;provider=Devart.Data.Oracle;
....">
```

I still get the error "The specified metadata path is not valid".

Do I need to move the meta files to the class library root directory?

**Edit**
I have tried using `res://*/Models.DataModel.csdl` etc. but got the error "Unable to load the specified metadata resource." instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to embed the metadata files in the assembly by changing the output from **CopyToOutputDirectory** to **EmbedInOutputAssembly**

This would allow `res://*/Model.ssdl` etc. to work

Answer (score 2):

When the EF model is located in a separate/project (MyCompany.MyApp.Infra) which is used by another project, you need to correctly configure the connection string in the app.config or web.config

See this example:

**MyContext.cs** in MyCompany.MyApp.Infra project.

```
namespace MyCompany.MyApp.Domain
{
    using System.Data.Objects;

    /// <summary>
    /// The MyContext
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyContext : ObjectContext, IUnitOfWork
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The ConnectionString
        /// </summary>
        public const string ConnectionString = "name=MyContext";

        /// <summary>
        /// The ContainerName
        /// </summary>
        public const string ContainerName = "MyContext";

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MyContext"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public MyContext()
            : base(ConnectionString, ContainerName)
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**web.config** in Silverlight Web Project

```
<add name="MyContext"
connectionString="metadata=res://MyCompany.MyApp.Infra/DataModel.MyContext.csdl|
                           res://MyCompany.MyApp.Infra/DataModel.MyContext.ssdl|
                           res://MyCompany.MyApp.Infra/DataModel.MyContext.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=localhost\DB_01;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=usr;Password=pwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
/>
```

Comment: Thx Stef, it's really helpful to me.